# How do I collect my generated numbers in a range?

Tags: java, arrays, integer, jcreator

Currently I have a code that generates 200 random numbers between 0-100 (10 numbers per line) but now I am stuck because I want to have it count all the numbers between 0-20,21-40,41-60,61-80,81-100 and tell me how many numbers are in that range. How would I do it? I have tried but I had just generated numbers between those ranges. Here is my current code: 
(And if possible how to do it with arrays? I'm a beginner and still learning)

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomStats1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random random = new Random ();

System.out.println("200 Generated numbers, 10 per line: ");
int numbersOnThisLine = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
{
int nextNumber = random.nextInt(100);
    System.out.print(nextNumber + " ");
    numbersOnThisLine++;

 if (numbersOnThisLine == 10)
 {
   System.out.print("\n");
   numbersOnThisLine = 0;
}

}
}
}
```

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: You realise that `nextInt(100)` gives values from 0 to 99 not 100. Also your equal sizes ranges would be 0-19, 20-39, 40-59, 60-79, 80-99.  0-20 is 21 numbers.

Comment: Oh, my bad. Now that I got that fixed do you have some idea how to have it count the numbers between the ranges?

Comment: If you want a really simple solution, create variables for each of the ranges to count each time a number falls in that range.  For example, `countOf0to19`, `countOf20to39`, `countOf40to59`, `countOf60to79`, `countOf80to99`.  Then check which range the random number falls in, and add one to the count in the loop.

Comment: It may help to start by writing down a step-by-step process how you would do this on paper.  Then try to convert that process into code.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're in learning phase and you should use arrays, I will only give you recommendations:

1. `nextInt(100)` gives values from 0 to 99, not 100.
2. Your equal sizes ranges would be 0-19, 20-39, 40-59, 60-79, 80-99. 0-20 is 21 numbers.

   (Notes above taken from [Peter Lawrey's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19778494/how-do-i-collect-my-generated-numbers-in-a-range#comment29398394_19778494)).
3. You may use an array that will serve to store the counters of each group. Since you have 5 groups, define the size of your array as 5 as well.
4. Taking some advantage of the language, the result of the integer division of two numbers is the integer part of the double result. In other words, when dividing `int x` by `int y`, the result `int z` will be the integer part of the result, no modulus and no floating part to think about. For example:

   - 15 / 20 = 0
   - 20 / 20 = 1
   - 21 / 20 = 1
5. By the note above, you can easily get the index of the array that will serve as counter as dividing the generated number between 0 and 100 and just dividing it by 20.

A small pseudocode:

```
int counterSize <- 5
int groupSize <- 20
int[] counter = new int[counterSize]
for i <- 0 to 200
    int nextNumber <- random(100)
    int index <- nextNumber / groupSize
    counter[index] <- counter[index] + 1
end for
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `HashMap<Integer,HashSet<Integer>>` and initialize it with the values:0, 20, 40, 60 and 80 (and empty Sets):

```
HashMap<Integer,HashSet<Integer>> map = new HashMap<Integer,HashSet<Integer>>();
map.put(0, new HashSet<Integer>());
map.put(20, new HashSet<Integer>());
...
```

Whenever you generate a number, check in which range does it fall, for example, if it's in the range 21-40 you should add it to the HashMap as follows:

```
map.get(20).add(number);
```

after your're done generating the numbers you'll have them sorted by range in Sets.

**Remark:**
A Set will not allow duplicate members, so if you want to allow repetitions, don't use `HashSet`, use a `List` or another data structure that allows it.

Comment: No offense, but judging by the expertise level of the question, I don't think giving a solution with `HashMap` or `Set` is appropriate.

Comment: @mellamokb None taken. But please provide a reason/explanation to your comment otherwise it's not constructive.

Comment: Yeah, I'm still learning. If possible could you make it more beginner like? Because I have no idea what HashMap is.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my comment to clarify.  This looks like a beginner/homework type question, and the user is struggling even with arrays.  I think your solution is excellent, but might be beyond the scope of OP's expertise :)

Comment: In other words, OP's learning about algorithms and how to code them, so using Java already-built structures like `Map` backed by `HashMap` and `Set` backed by `HashSet` won't help OP achieve these lessons.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I forgot to say that I was a beginner. Would you be able to find the numbers in a specific range with arrays?

Comment: By the way, this approach is really heavy to use for such a simple use case.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza this approach is heavy if all you want to do is count the group-sizes, but if you want to generated numbers to be sorted by groups - that's a good approach.

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys - I finally got it :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to store them in a datastructure like an `ArrayList`.

```
private List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0; i < 200; i++){
 int nextNumber = random.nextInt(100);
 numbers.add(nextNumber);
}
```

This will keep all our numbers together.

Now to determine the amount of numbers in certain ranges we can create our own custom class since Java doesn't provide this.

```
private class Range {
 private int lower;
 private int higher;

 public Range(int low, int high) {
  lower = low;
  higher = high;
 }

 // Getters

 public bool isValid(int i){
  return (i > lower && i < higher);
 }

 @Override 
 public int GetHashCode(){
  return lower;
 }

 @Override
 public bool Equals(Object o){
  if(!(o instanceOf Range)) { return false; }
  return ((Range)o).GetLower() == this.lower;
 }
}
```

Now we can use this in a `Map`:

```
private Map<Range, Integer> occurrences = new HashMap<Range, Integer>();
```

And initialize it with ranges:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i+= 20){
 occurrences.put(new Range(i, i + 20), 0);
}
```

And simply iterate over our previous list:

```
for(int i : numbers) {
 for(Range key : occurrences.KeySet()){
  if(key.isValid(i) { occurrences.put(i); } 
 }
}
```

I realize it is elaborate and might not suit your required level. At least this is the thought process I'd take, you can take from it what you like. It might help future browsers after all.

**More simple (no extra class needed):**

```
private List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
private Map<Integer, Integer> occurrences = new HashMap<>();

for(int i = 0; i < 200; i++){
 int nextNumber = random.nextInt(100);
 numbers.add(nextNumber);
}

for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
 occurrences.put(i, 0);
}

for(int i : numbers){
 int sofar = occurrences.get(i);
 occurrences.put(i, sofar + 1);
}
```

And to get the actual data in a range:

```
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
 count+= occurences.get(i);
 if(i % 20 == 0) {
  System.out.println("From " + i - 20 + " to " + i + ":" + count);
  count = 0;
 }
}
```

**With arrays, more simple and loss of individual values:**

```
private int[] occ = new int[5];

for(int i = 0; i < 200; i++){
 int nextNumber = random.nextInt(100);
 System.out.println(nextnumber);

 if(i <= 20) { occ[0]++; }
 if(i <= 40) { occ[1]++; }
 if(i <= 60) { occ[2]++; }
 if(i <= 80) { occ[3]++; }
 if(i <= 100) { occ[4]++; }
}

System.out.println("Numbers from 0 to 20: " + occ[0]); 
System.out.println("Numbers from 20 to 40: " + occ[1]); 
System.out.println("Numbers from 40 to 60: " + occ[2]); 
System.out.println("Numbers from 60 to 80: " + occ[3]); 
System.out.println("Numbers from 80 to 100: " + occ[4]);
```

Comment: I'm still learning Java and I do not really understand this since I'm a beginner. If possible could you make it easier?

Comment: @user2809115: take a look at my edit and see the second example. It's a lot shorter. If you want any more information just point to the line that causes confusion and I'll explain it.

Comment: I saw one of my friends did it and he did it with arrays and it was pretty short, can you use arrays in something like this?

Comment: @user2809115: fine, last edit contains arrays and is shorter. This will not store the separate random values though, once they're printed out you lose them. You do keep track of the amount of random values in a range though.

Comment: More simple: no need to use `if`s.

Comment: Alright, for an even shorter approach you can take a look at @LuiggiMendoza's answer. With the requirement for beginner's code I believe my last edit might be more suited though.

Comment: Sorry if this is stupid question but what is occ? Like in occ[4]++;

Comment: @user2809115 that's the name of the integer array variable.

Comment: @user2809115: it's the name of the array as defined here `private int[] occ = new int[5];`. It's how you will address the array like any other variable.

Comment: By the way, you can't have `List<int>` since generics is for classes only, not for primitive types, so this won't compile, instead use `List<Integer>`.

Comment: True, looked over it and copied it. Changed now.

Comment: Did you mean to write `if(i % 19 == 0) {` about 3/4 of the way through?

Comment: @DavidWallace: I think this post is putting my mind to sleep. I got carried away with the 0-19, 0-20 issue. Should be `20` indeed.